# How to compare a new value to last value in the table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in MySQL database. I have a table (myData) with 3 columns. Date, Values, and Status. What I am trying to achieve is, when a new value comes, if it is higher than the last value, It should insert 1 in the Status column. If it is less than the last value, It should insert 0 in the status column. I couldn't find a logic to do it. Any suggestions, please?

```
BEGIN
IF new.Values > // what should be here?
 THEN
 INSERT INTO //

END
```

Comment: What happens if it's equal? And why store easily dervable data?

Comment: if same, insert 0.  I am making some graph out of this info.

Comment: Still, just calculate the result when you need it.

Comment: I just wanna use all the dates where status was 1. I thought it would be easy if I have a column with status infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |    12 |
|  3 |    13 |
|  4 |     9 |
|  5 |     7 |
|  6 |     6 |
|  7 |     8 |
|  8 |     3 |
|  9 |    10 |
| 10 |     1 |
| 11 |    18 |
| 12 |     4 |
| 13 |     6 |
| 14 |     0 |
| 15 |     2 |
| 16 |     8 |
| 17 |    14 |
| 18 |     7 |
| 19 |    15 |
| 20 |    11 |
| 21 |    12 |
| 22 |     7 |
| 23 |    20 |
| 24 |    17 |
| 25 |     8 |
| 26 |     6 |
| 27 |     6 |
| 28 |    12 |
| 29 |     3 |
| 30 |    18 |
| 31 |     1 |
| 32 |    12 |
+----+-------+

SELECT a.*
     , b.value >= a.value n
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) next
         FROM my_table x
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.id > x.id
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.next = a.id;
+----+-------+------+
| id | value | n    |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |     2 | NULL |
|  2 |    12 |    0 |
|  3 |    13 |    0 |
|  4 |     9 |    1 |
|  5 |     7 |    1 |
|  6 |     6 |    1 |
|  7 |     8 |    0 |
|  8 |     3 |    1 |
|  9 |    10 |    0 |
| 10 |     1 |    1 |
| 11 |    18 |    0 |
| 12 |     4 |    1 |
| 13 |     6 |    0 |
| 14 |     0 |    1 |
| 15 |     2 |    0 |
| 16 |     8 |    0 |
| 17 |    14 |    0 |
| 18 |     7 |    1 |
| 19 |    15 |    0 |
| 20 |    11 |    1 |
| 21 |    12 |    0 |
| 22 |     7 |    1 |
| 23 |    20 |    0 |
| 24 |    17 |    1 |
| 25 |     8 |    1 |
| 26 |     6 |    1 |
| 27 |     6 |    1 |
| 28 |    12 |    0 |
| 29 |     3 |    1 |
| 30 |    18 |    0 |
| 31 |     1 |    1 |
| 32 |    12 |    0 |
+----+-------+------+
```

If all you want is the rows where n=1, then the query is actually even simpler...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) next
         FROM my_table x
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.id > x.id
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.next = a.id
   AND b.value >= a.value;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  4 |     9 |
|  5 |     7 |
|  6 |     6 |
|  8 |     3 |
| 10 |     1 |
| 12 |     4 |
| 14 |     0 |
| 18 |     7 |
| 20 |    11 |
| 22 |     7 |
| 24 |    17 |
| 25 |     8 |
| 26 |     6 |
| 27 |     6 |
| 29 |     3 |
| 31 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Perfect. But your answer is exactly the opposite of what I wanted.  You picked the value which is less than the last values! But thanks ;)

Comment: So now you know what to do ;-)